# HtmlPurifier: how to whitelist img src?

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

Is there an option to make HTMLPurifier remove all the images, whose `src` location is not pointing to one of the trusted domains?

Answer (score 0):

Use %URI.DisableExternalResources.

**Edit:** Actually, this is not a complete solution, as it prevents all external images from being shown, and doesn't let you specify a trusted domain.